# Trying to get the selected attribute to work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make my selected menu have a selected attribute when it's chosen. The problem I'm having is that when the option is chosen it still goes to the first option available.

Here is my code

```
<div class="content_wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form action="{{ route('account.sort-orders') }}">
                <select class="sort_orders" name="sort_orders">
                    <option class="all" value="all" selected>All</option>
                    <option class="three_months" value="three_months">Last 3 months</option>
                    <option class="six_months" value="six_months">Last 6 months</option>
                    <option class="2019" value="2019">2019</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sort_orders').change(function(){
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        });

        $("select.sort_orders").change(function(){
            var selectedOpton = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            console.log("You have selected this option - " + selectedCountry);

            if(selectedOpton == 'three_months'){
                console.log('this is three_months');
                $('.all').removeAttr('selected');
                $('.three_months').attr('selected', true);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're expecting this code to solve? I ask because the point of the code is completely redundant. If you've chosen 'Three months' then no other option can be selected, unless you're using a multiple select, which you're not. Therefore the `removeAttr()`/`attr()` logic is pointless - it happens by default when using the default HTML control

Comment: I have updated my answer, which should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly more efficient ways to do this. However, I think this is what you're trying to achieve.

```
<div class="content_wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form action="{{ route('account.sort-orders') }}">
                <select id="yourSlct" class="sort_orders" name="sort_orders">
                    <option class="all" value="all" selected>All</option>
                    <option id="option2" class="three_months" value="three_months">Last 3 months</option>
                    <option class="six_months" value="six_months">Last 6 months</option>
                    <option class="2019" value="2019">2019</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sort_orders').change(function(){
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });

    $("select.sort_orders").change(function(){
        var selectedOpton = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $('#text').text(selectedOpton);

        $('#yourSlct').children().removeAttr("selected");

        if(selectedOpton == 'three_months'){
            console.log('this is three_months');
            $("select.sort_orders #option2").attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: I made my controller function give the attribute `selected` and even though that worked. I'm hoping that there is a better way to do it with jquery. The reason why I thought of doing it through my controller was because of my page being refreshed.

Comment: @Nikki Are you sure that you added all the IDs etc? I tried this in JS Fiddle and it was working for me. I edited the HTML and the JS, perhaps try copy and pasting my answer.